# PHP Laravel on Linux Server - How to allow Linux Program to create/write a file in public folder?

Tags: php, laravel

The context : I have a linux server with a linux executable, this executable read a JSON file created by a page on the website, run algorithm and create a JSON file to store the calcuation value in output.

SO with MAMP on local(on Windows) it's working but on the linux server, I have an Error 500 because the output.json does not exist because not created by the executable.

The "HIC" was the input.json file was created by php/laravel in the same folder whitout error !

I have look many answer/solution for permissions rights but it's all the same and not working at all ..

There was 2 executable : One for windows and another for linux. Both are launched by .bat file.

Below the working function :

```
//Lancement Moteur
public function launchAlgo(){
  //Temporisation le temps de création des fichiers temporaires contenant les données des fichiers CSV
  //sleep(2);

  //Ecriture du fichier JSON contenant les datas saisies
  $this->writeJson();

  //Execution du Moteur qui prend en entrée le fichier JSON "input.json"
  if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
  {
    //Windows (via un batch)
    $good = pclose(popen('start /wait exe\eleccurve\launch.bat', 'r'));
  }
  else
  {
    //Linux (via un batch)
    $good = pclose(popen('start /wait exe/eleccurve/launchub.bat', 'r'));
    //$cmd = shell_exec('./exe/eleccurve/ElecCurveMotor');
  }

  //Temporisation le temps de création du fichier output.json par l'executable
  sleep(2);

  //Lecture du fichier JSON en sortie du moteur "output.json"
  $this->readJson();

  //L'affichage des informations contenues ds le JSON se fait via le modèle ds la page de validation
  //Renvoi vers la page de validation de la courbe
  $this->goToValidateCurve();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error message.

Comment: "500 Server Error" on the browser and in inspection : "POST http://192.168.1.21/livewire/message/curve 500 (Internal Server Error)" index.js:40

Comment: You need to either turn better error reporting on or find the error logs as that error doesn't help.

Comment: When I deploy I make this after cloning from git : 

sudo chgrp -R www-data DICOGEN
sudo chown -R root DICOGEN
sudo chmod -R 775 DICOGEN
sudo chmod -R 775 DICOGEN/storage ou sudo chmod -R o+w DICOGEN/storage
cd DICOGEN
mv .env_production .env 
composer install
cd ..
sudo chgrp -R www-data DICOGEN
sudo chown -R root DICOGEN
sudo chmod -R 775 DICOGEN
sudo chmod -R 775 DICOGEN/storage

Comment: In the laravel.log :
local.ERROR: file_get_contents(exe/eleccurve/output.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
{"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(exe/eleccurve/output.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/html/DICOGEN/app/Http/Livewire/Curve.php:263)

Comment: I thought `start` and `.bat` only worked on windows so your Linux code branch would not work

Comment: Oh okay, so using script.sh is better ?

Comment: I've make a script .sh, it's working with console but not by the website page .. 

The script : 
#! /bin/sh
sudo ./ElecCurveMotor

The code in PHP :  $cmd = shell_exec('sudo ./exe/eleccurve/scriptub.sh');

And error 500 on server : 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)